# how to write post-commit hook to automatically synchronize two repositories

Tags: svn, ssl, version-control

I am trying to synchronize two repositories using subversion (SVN), and am using visualSVN on both source and mirror servers.

I am able to synchronize them manually, i.e. through command-line, But i want it to be triggered automatically using a post commit hook of a master repository.

I am writing the following code in post-commit hook of the source repository (master) to automatically sync with mirror repository (slave):

```
svnsync --non-interactive --sync-username syncuser --sync-password syncuserpassword sync mirror-repository-url
```

But when i check in some file to the source repository (master) it shows the following error:

```
**post-commit hook failed(exit code 1) with output:

svnsync:E230001:Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'mirror-repository-url' svnsync:E230001:Server SSL certificate verification failed; Certificate issued for a different hostname; issuer is not trusted**
```

But i am getting file in source repository in SVN (master) but not to the mirror repository (slave), so I tried manually giving the same code which was written in post-commit hook of master repository through command line of the mirror server , then mirror repository(slave) got synchronized with the new revision added to the source repository(master)

How do I overcome this problem while synchronizing automatically using post-commit hook? Where did I go wrong? Can you suggest some idea to overcome this error?

Answer (score 1):

> so i tried manually giving the same code which was written in post-commit hook of master repository through command line of the mirror server

First, you are testing on the wrong server. If there is a problem with the execution of the post-commit hook on the master server, then you should test your commands on the master server.

Usually when you see a difference in behavior between the command line and in the context of a post-commit hook, it is related to the fact that no environment variables are set. From the [SVN book section on hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks):

> For security reasons, the Subversion repository executes hook programs with an empty environment—that is, no environment variables are set at all, not even $PATH (or %PATH%, under Windows). Because of this, many administrators are baffled when their hook program runs fine by hand, but doesn't work when run by Subversion. Be sure to explicitly set any necessary environment variables in your hook program and/or use absolute paths to programs.

Comment: I tried after creating environment variable but still it is showing same error. Please show how to create environment variable for that in the post-commit hook so that it will work fine ?

Comment: @satish: First you should check whether the behavior is different between a command line and the post-commit hook. What happens if you enter the command on the command line on the master server?

Comment: After i entered the command on the command line of the master server it works fine and synchronized the pending revisions of master repository with slave repository i.e., copied pending revisions to the  mirror repository.